# Use python to pull info from a .txt file and sum numbers by customer and by product

Tags: python

I have the following text file:

```
Customer   Product   Amount
Lynn        MAF       1750
Lynn        HAR       1950
Ken         RSF       1350
Dave        MAF       1000
```

I need to pull the product amount from this text file using Python and sum the values by customer name and sum the values by product code.
Desired outputs should look like:

Sum by customer name should print out:

```
Lynn 3700 
Ken 1350
Dave 1000
```

Sum by product code should print out:

```
MAF 2750
HAR 1950
RSF 1350
```

This is my code:

```
f2 = open("transactions.txt", "r")          #open and read transactions.txt file
headers2 = f2.readline()
data2 = f2.readlines()
print(headers2)
reportList = {}
for line in data2:
    line_split = line.split()
    reportList[line_split[0]] = [line_split[1],line_split[2]]#,line_split[3]]

grouping_choice = input("How would you like to group the sales - [P]: by product or [C]: by customer?").lower()
if grouping_choice == "p":                       #product grouping
    print(f'Product \t\t Total Sales')
   
    menu()                                     

elif grouping_choice == "c":                     #customer grouping
    print(f'Customer \t\t Total Sales')

    menu()
else:
    print("Error, you selected an invalid choice!")       #invalid selection, sends back to report menu
    report()
```

Comment: What is `menu`?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
You haven't demonstrated any problem with your code.  Isolate the problem: start by replacing the input sequence with a hard-coded data set.

Comment: Consider using PANDAS for this; the groupby / sum combination makes your code a couple of lines long.

Comment: @Tomerikoo menu() is a defined function that pulls the user back to the menu where they can select from 6 options on what they want to do. This part of the code is part of a larger program that allows users to navigate a bike store, to buy items, add customer data, find customer data and leave the program

Comment: Then you need to include in your question, both the PANDAS restriction and the fact that this is homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to have 2 different dictionaries

```
name_amount_map = {}
code_amount_map = {}
with open('transactions.txt', 'r') as file:
    header = file.readline()
    for line in file.readlines():
        name, code, amount = line.split()
        name_amount_map[name] = name_amount_map.get(name, 0) + int(amount)
        code_amount_map[code] = code_amount_map.get(code, 0) + int(amount)

i = input("How would you like to group the sales - [P]: by product or [C]: by customer?").lower()
if i == 'c':
    print(name_amount_map)
elif i == 'p':
    print(code_amount_map)
```

Comment: Thank you! This code worked and helped a ton!

Comment: Hi @ElDiablo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.